# How can i make an xml element with enumeration content not repeatable

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to have several instances of element videogame, each one need to have one or several elements console but withouth being repeated inside each element videogame.
Element console contents is gottem from an enumeration.

My videogame example looks as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="tVideojuego">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="a:tSoftware">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="consola" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:enumeration value="XBox"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="Play 4"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="Nintendo Switch"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="PC"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:unique name="consolaUnica">
                            <xs:selector xpath="consola"></xs:selector>
                            <xs:field xpath="."></xs:field>
                        </xs:unique>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

However inside each element videogame i can have PC more than one and i don't want to allow it.

For example, next videogame element is not allowed because pc appears 3 times and 2 of them with same content:

```
<ar:videojuego>
        <id>videojuegoTheDivision2</id>
        <nombre>The Division 2</nombre>
        <cantidadArticulo>879</cantidadArticulo>
        <empresa>Ubisoft</empresa>
        <consola>PC</consola>
        <consola>PC</consola>
        <consola>Nintendo Switch</consola>
    </ar:videojuego>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right lines, but the `xs:unique` can only reference child items, and can only be associated with an element. So the constraint needs to go on the element **containing** the `consola` elements.

Which means you need to apply the constraint where you use `tVideojuego`, not in its definition (which is not ideal).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="tSoftware" />
    <xs:complexType name="tVideojuego">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tSoftware">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="consola" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:enumeration value="XBox" />
                                <xs:enumeration value="Play 4" />
                                <xs:enumeration value="Nintendo Switch" />
                                <xs:enumeration value="PC" />
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Sample">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="VideoGame" type="tVideojuego">
                    <xs:unique name="consolaUnica">
                        <xs:selector xpath="consola"></xs:selector>
                        <xs:field xpath="."></xs:field>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]